# Реализация метода шаблонного класса в *.cpp или задать размер массива, который является членом класса через конструктор

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++

Массив std::array является членом класса. Нужно задавать его размер через конструктор. С этим вроде разобрался:

Com.h:

```
#include <array>

template <uint8_t data_size>
class Com
{
public:
    Com(uint8_t type);
    void write();
private:
    uint8_t _type;
    std::array<uint32_t, data_size> _data;
};
```

Com.cpp:

```
#include "com.h"

template <uint8_t data_size>
Com<data_size>::Com(uint8_t type)
{
    _type = type;
};
```

Проблема: как реализовать методы класса в cpp файле?
Как для обычного класса `void Com::write(){}` не работает:
*error: 'Com' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration*

Желательно обойтись без std::vector, нужен статический массив.

Если делать так:

```
template <uint8_t data_size>
void Com<data_size>::write()
{
}
```

то уже линкер ругается:
Undefined symbol Com<(unsigned char)8>::Com(unsigned char) (referred from BUILD/source/main.o).

UPD: линкер ругается как раз таки на реализацию конструктора в cpp файле, а не метода.

Comment: Вы, ставя метку "шаблоны", читали ее описание? Ну и где в вашем вопросе шаблоны *проектирования*? Перед тем, как что-то писать - надо почитать, а вы даже первую страницу сайта не прочли (иначе бы уже получили бронзовую медаль, которой у вас нет :)).

Comment: Не стоит выносить определения шаблонных классов и функций в cpp файлы

Comment: Размер std::array не может быть задан через конструктор, это параметр времени компиляции.

Answer (score 0):

Как [обычно](https://ideone.com/iAv7KW):

```
template <uint8_t data_size>
void Com<data_size>::write()
{
    ....
};
```